# File type fields shows Maximum upload size below file field. Needs to remove that in joomla

Tags: php, xml, joomla

I have created a field [image: Mobile numbers upload file field] in our joomla component. But it shows Maximum upload size value below the field while shows it in the view.

But this issue is only appear in joomla 3.7.2 before i used this same component in joomla 3.6.5 the field shows without that Max Upload size value. And this value is taken from Memory_size value in PHP.ini that is 100MB. But this value is too much for our process.

So that we don't want to show that value with that field. How can achieve this?
i attached the screen shot of the field

Comment: Try to hide the field with CSS `{display:hide;}`

Comment: Hello, We didn't write any code to show Maximum upload size. I think in latest joomla there may some codes added.  The below code we used for that field.
<field name="uploaduser"
   type="file"
   required="true"
   label="BULK_UPLOADV_FILE"
   description="BULK_UPLOADV_FILE_DESC" />

Comment: And also we don't want to hide entire field only the content [Maximum upload size: 100.00 MB] shows under the field. Thats why i am asking in latest joomla version any code standard maintained to show the Maximum upload size: 100.00 MB from PHP ini file of server.

Answer (score 0):

Proceed step by step with the simple solution below:

1. In your template creates the directory structure: your_template/html/layouts/joomla/form/field/
2. Copy file layouts/joomla/form/field/file.php and paste in the your template in the final directory created
3. Edit this file and comment or delete last line:

<?php echo JText::sprintf('JGLOBAL_MAXIMUM_UPLOAD_SIZE_LIMIT', $maxSize); ?>

Work fine in Joomla 3.8.2